# NiceTabular: Space between columns too large

Tags: spacing, columns, nicematrix

I want to have this table I plotted but the margin between the first column and the second should be reduced in order for the last column not be that squeezed. Would you have any other imputs for improvement?

```
% page setup 
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

% color
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}

% graphics
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx} 
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false 
]{caption}

\newenvironment{conditions}
    {\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X}}
    {\endtabularx}

% units 
\usepackage{siunitx} %  comprehensive (SI) units package


% tables
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \caption{TheCaption.}
\scriptsize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\scriptsize}c*{4}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}@{}}[colortbl-like]
\toprule 
\textbf{\makecell[l]{Time step}}& \textbf{\makecell[l]{Time [\si{\minute}]}} & \textbf{\makecell[l]{Assay A}} & \textbf{\makecell[l]{Assay B}} & \textbf{\makecell[l]{Assay C}} \\
\midrule
\rowcolor{lightmintbg}\Block{3-1}{0}    & 0  & $+$ Enzymes &    - & - \\
\rowcolor{lightmintbg}                  & 1  &-            &    - & -  \\
\rowcolor{lightmintbg}                  & 2  &-            &    - & $+$ Enzymes \\


\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular*}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: thepic]

With solution (there is an error!!!)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

% color
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}

% graphics
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%\newenvironment{conditions}
%    {\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X}}
%    {\endtabularx}

% units
\usepackage{siunitx} %  comprehensive (SI) units package

% tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

    \begin{table}
    \caption{The Caption.}
    \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2pt}
\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} 
                                w{c}{\dimexpr0.11\linewidth-1\tabcolsep}
                                w{c}{\dimexpr0.11\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                           *{2}{W{l}{\dimexpr0.26\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
                                W{l}{\dimexpr0.26\linewidth-1\tabcolsep} 
                                 @{}}
\CodeBefore
\rectanglecolor{lightmintbg}{2-1}{4-5}
\rectanglecolor{lightmintbg}{8-7}{10-11}
\rectanglecolor{lightmintbg}{14-13}{16-17}
\rectanglecolor{lightmintbg}{20-19}{22-23}
\Body
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Time\\ step}    
    & \thead[l]{Time\\ [\si{\minute}]}
        & \thead[l]{Assay A}
            & \thead[l]{Assay B}
                & \thead[l]{Assay C}        \\
    \midrule
\Block{3-1}{0}    & 0  & $+$ Enzymes &    - & - \\
                  & 1  &-            &    - & -  \\
                  & 2  &-            &    - & $+$ Enzymes \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{I}   & 3   & 1 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 4   & -     &    - & 1 C \\
                  & 5   & -     &  1 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{II}  & 6   & 2 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 7   & -     &    - & 2 C \\
                  & 8   & -     &  2 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{III}  & 9   & 3 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 10   & -     &    - & 3 C \\
                  & 11   & -     &  3 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{IV}   & 12   & 4 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 13   & -     &    - & 4 C \\
                  & 14   & -     &  4 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{V}    & 15   & 5 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 16   & -     &    - & 5 C \\
                  & 17  & -     &  5 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{VI}   & 18   & 6 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 19   & -     &    - & 6 C \\
                  & 20   & -     &  6 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{VII}  & 21   & 7 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 22   & -     &    - & 7 C \\
                  & 23   & -     &  7 B & - \\

\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular*}
   \label{tab:time}
\end{table}
```

The table should look like this:

[image: like this]

Comment: I don't understand why you use the starred version of `{NiceTabular}` (that is to say `{NiceTabular*}`. I would use `{NiceTabular}` and add (maybe) space between columns with the classical construction `@{\hskip ...}`.

Comment: so there is no solution using the starred version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Similarly as in @Simon Dispa [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595472/nicetabular-space-between-columns-too-large/595490#595490) (+1), you need to define widths of columns, for example with macro `\dimexpr`, where consider `\tabcolsep` at each column.

**Edit:**

Width of cells is calculated on estimation, how width the first two column should be, i.e. about `0.11\linewidth`, rest of table width is distributed to rest of columns: 2 x 0.11 + 3 x 0.26 = 1. From each column width are substracted `tabcolsep` in this columns: from first on the last one (since they due to used `@{}` at begin and end of column specification haven't the first and the last `\tabcolsep`) and from other two.

Coloring of block of cells in table is defined by

```
\rectanglecolor{<color>}{<top left cell of block>}{<bottom right cell in block>}
```

In your case top left cell is in 2. row in the first column: `{2-1}` and bottom right cell is 4. row in the fifth column: `{4-5}`.

According to your edited question, the correct code for color blocks are:

```
\CodeBefore
\rectanglecolor{lightmintbg}{2-1}{4-5}
\rectanglecolor{lightmintbg}{8-1}{10-5}
\rectanglecolor{lightmintbg}{14-1}{16-5}
\rectanglecolor{lightmintbg}{20-1}{22-5}
\Body
```

which produce considering table code in edited question:

[image]

Original MWE, which produce the first image of your table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

% color
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}

% graphics
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%\newenvironment{conditions}
%    {\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X}}
%    {\endtabularx}

% units
\usepackage{siunitx} %  comprehensive (SI) units package

% tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{The Caption.}
    \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 2pt}
\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} 
                                w{c}{\dimexpr0.11\linewidth-1\tabcolsep}
                                w{c}{\dimexpr0.11\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
                           *{2}{W{l}{\dimexpr0.26\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
                                W{l}{\dimexpr0.26\linewidth-1\tabcolsep} 
                                 @{}}
\CodeBefore
\rectanglecolor{blue!15}{2-1}{4-5}
\Body
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Time\\ step}    
    & \thead[l]{Time\\ [\si{\minute}]}
        & \thead[l]{Assay A}
            & \thead[l]{Assay B}
                & \thead[l]{Assay C}        \\
    \midrule
\Block{3-1}{0}    
    & 0  & $+$ Enzymes &    - & -           \\
    & 1  &-            &    - & -           \\
    & 2  &-            &    - & $+$ Enzymes \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE are done some tweaks for make code shorter.

Comment: How do you calculate the width for each column to reach exactly one line. Could you explain this a bit more in order I understand a bit better? Because I do not feel capable to do this my own

Comment: I just added the the applied version of your solution. I added some more \rectanglecolor ... could you help me to find the error I did?

Comment: @Elia, I will add description, how column width are calculated ASAP. Regarding coloring table, your block definitions are out of table. What and how you like to color your table?

Comment: @ Zarko: Thank you very much for the description. Regarding the coloring of the table I added a picture of what is compiled because that corresponds to what I want but because of the reason you mentioned there is an error in the code.

Comment: @Elia, see edited answer.

Comment: Amazing! It is very clear to understand :D

Answer (score 6):

Set the width of the first column and distribute the remaining space between the others.

[image: a]

```
% page setup 
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

% color
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}
\colorlet{lightmintbg}{mintbg!40}

% graphics
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx} 
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false 
]{caption}

\newenvironment{conditions}
{\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} X}}
{\endtabularx}

% units 
\usepackage{siunitx} %  comprehensive (SI) units package


% tables
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\usepackage{calc}% added <<<

\begin{document}
    
    \newlength{\firstcolumn}
    \newlength{\othercolumn}
    
    \setlength{\firstcolumn}{60pt} % set the first column width
    \setlength{\othercolumn}{(\textwidth-\firstcolumn-8\tabcolsep)/4} % the width of the other columns
    

    \begin{table}
        \caption{TheCaption.}
        \scriptsize
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
        \begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\scriptsize}wc{\firstcolumn}  *{4}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}Wl{\othercolumn}}@{}}[colortbl-like] % changed <<<< w W from package array
            \toprule 
            \textbf{\makecell[l]{Time step}}& \textbf{\makecell[l]{Time [\si{\minute}]}} & \textbf{\makecell[l]{Assay A}} & \textbf{\makecell[l]{Assay B}} & \textbf{\makecell[l]{Assay C}} \\
            \midrule
            \rowcolor{lightmintbg}\Block{3-1}{0}    & 0  & $+$ Enzymes &    - & - \\
            \rowcolor{lightmintbg}                  & 1  &-            &    - & -  \\
            \rowcolor{lightmintbg}                  & 2  &-            &    - & $+$ Enzymes \\          
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular*}
    \end{table} 
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.0 of 2021-08-10) provides `X` columns in the style of `tabularx` (and with a weight as option as in `tabularray` and in the obsolete package `tabu`).

Moreover, there is a command `\rowlistcolors` available in the `\CodeBefore`. With that command, it's easy to require an alternance of three blue rows followed by three white rows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mintbg}{rgb}{.63,.79,.95}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{text-series-to-math}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{The Caption.}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}X[11]X[11,c]X[26]X[26]X[26]@{}}
\CodeBefore
  \rowlistcolors{2}{mintbg!40,=,=,white,=,=}[restart]
\Body
\toprule
\RowStyle[cell-space-limits=3pt]{\bfseries}
\Block{}{Time\\ step}  
    & \Block{}{Time\\ [\si{\minute}]}
        & Assay A
            & Assay B
                & Assay C        \\
    \midrule
\Block{3-1}{0}    & 0  & $+$ Enzymes &    - & - \\
                  & 1  &-            &    - & -  \\
                  & 2  &-            &    - & $+$ Enzymes \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{I}   & 3   & 1 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 4   & -     &    - & 1 C \\
                  & 5   & -     &  1 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{II}  & 6   & 2 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 7   & -     &    - & 2 C \\
                  & 8   & -     &  2 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{III}  & 9   & 3 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 10   & -     &    - & 3 C \\
                  & 11   & -     &  3 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{IV}   & 12   & 4 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 13   & -     &    - & 4 C \\
                  & 14   & -     &  4 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{V}    & 15   & 5 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 16   & -     &    - & 5 C \\
                  & 17  & -     &  5 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{VI}   & 18   & 6 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 19   & -     &    - & 6 C \\
                  & 20   & -     &  6 B & - \\
\midrule
\Block{3-1}{VII}  & 21   & 7 A   &    - & - \\
                  & 22   & -     &    - & 7 C \\
                  & 23   & -     &  7 B & - \\

\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
   \label{tab:time}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]